# How can I make an erc20votes token an interchain token using axelar?

Tags: cross-chain

I’m trying to make a token interchain, my token is an erc20votes token

I tried deploying the ERC20votes contract through the axelar interchain token portal, registered it on avalanche as the main chain, and deployed to the bnb chain as a remote chain, all the functions work fine on the main chain (avalanche) and I was able to send tokens crosschain from avalanche to bnb, but when I test the erc20votes contract on the bnb chain (remote chain) and try to call some functions on it that are not native to the IERC20 interface like `delegate`, the transaction fails and I get this error after debugging from remix

`Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"The method \"debug_traceTransaction\" does not exist / is not available.","id":7108126628519236}`

How can I make the erc20votes token interchain so that I can call `delegate` and some other functions on the erc20votes contract on the remote chains?

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use the Interchain Token Service? This has been released on testnet and you can easily deploy interchain tokens with the same functionality across multiple chains. Have the native erc20 functions been working on the remote chain?